# NSMutableString stringWithString:NSString not working for me

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This piece of code below is causing my app to crash

***EDIT***

```
@interface termsAndConditions : NSObject 
{
NSMutableString *titleText;
NSMutableString *bodyText;
NSMutableArray *arrayBodyText;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *titleText;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *bodyText;
```

****EDIT****

```
else if ([[self.arrayBodyText objectAtIndex:x] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
  if (x == 0)
  {
   self.bodyText=[NSMutableString stringWithString:[self.arrayBodyText 
   objectAtIndex:x]];
  }
  else 
 {
  [self.bodyText appendString:[self.arrayBodyText objectAtIndex:x] ];
 }
```

the arrayBodyText is an array of NSString which I got from a dictionary and that I want to join them altogether in 1 NSMutableString.

When the app crashes it gives the message :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Basically I need help to read this array of NSStrings into 1 NSMutableString.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
self.bodyText = [[[self.arrayBodyText componentsJoinedByString:@""] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Comment: I'm guessing i need to replace the @"" in yourcode with the NSString object i get out of the array? Thanks Jeremy.

Comment: No, don't do that; use it as written. `-componentsJoinedByString:` concatenates the strings in the array with the supplied string as the separator. So, if the array were `{@"a", @"b", @"c"}`, and you sent it `componentsJoinedByString:@"***"`, the result would be `@"a***b***c"`.